# Align radiobuttons with text at right and button at left programmatically

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-relativelayout

I am trying to programmatically align the text of a radiobutton at left and the button at right instead of what is shown in the next screenshot

[image: normal radiobtns]

I tried to create dinamically a RelativeLayout and putting textview and radiobtn (without text) but every tries were unsuccessful :(

I post here the code I tried to run that I couldn't align.

```
        RelativeLayout relLay = new RelativeLayout(this);
        relLay.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));

        TextView textView=new TextView(this);
        textView.setText(device.getName());
        textView.setGravity(Gravity.LEFT);  

        RadioButton radioBtn= new RadioButton(this);
        radioBtn.setText(" ");
        radioBtn.setTag(device);
        radioBtn.setChecked(false);
        radioBtn.setGravity(Gravity.RIGHT); 

        RelativeLayout.LayoutParams lp1 = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(
                RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);

        lp1.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_LEFT, RelativeLayout.TRUE);
        RelativeLayout.LayoutParams lp2 = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(
                RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);

        lp2.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_RIGHT,RelativeLayout.TRUE);

        relLay.addView(textView,lp1);
        relLay.addView(radioBtn,lp2);
        radioGr.addView(relLay);
```

I have also to remark that i'm adding the relativelayouts in a radiogroup that it's contained itself by a ScrollView.

Thank you in advance for your help and patience

Answer (score 0):

you can use following code for it :

```
RelativeLayout relLay = new RelativeLayout(this);
            relLay.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
            relLay.setGravity(Gravity.RIGHT);
            TextView textView=new TextView(this);
            textView.setText("good");
            textView.setGravity(Gravity.RIGHT);  
            RadioButton radioBtn= new RadioButton(this);
            radioBtn.setChecked(false);
            radioBtn.setId(125); //you must setid for radioBtn

            RelativeLayout.LayoutParams lp1 = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(
                    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);

          lp1.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_LEFT, RelativeLayout.TRUE);
            RelativeLayout.LayoutParams lp2 = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(
                 RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
            lp1.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_BASELINE,radioBtn.getId());
          lp1.addRule(RelativeLayout.LEFT_OF,radioBtn.getId());
            lp2.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_RIGHT, RelativeLayout.TRUE);
            relLay.addView(radioBtn,lp2);
            relLay.addView(textView,lp1);
            this.setContentView(relLay);
```